# How to add commas to an array created by user input?

Tags: ruby

I'm struggling with something I'm working on:

```
puts "What are your test scores?"
test_scores = gets.chomp.to_a
```

Basically I want to get the user's test scores, add them together and divide by the number of scores they give. I know I can use `length` to see the number of tests scores in the array and `inject(:+)` to add the numbers within the array, but what if the user doesn't use a comma to separate the grades?

```
test_scores = [90 87 07]
```

I can't use `inject` without commas in place so how would I add the commas in between the numbers if the user doesn't? And then how do I keep from adding the commas if the user already has them in place?

Comment: It would be really useful if you could give us examples of all of the kinds of input your program will accept, and how the program should interpret it. Your description is somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
puts "What are your test scores?"
test_scores = gets.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
puts test_scores.inject(:+)/test_scores.size
```

Now I am running the code :-

```
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby -v test.rb
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [i686-linux]
What are your test scores?
12 33 12
19
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby> ruby -v test.rb
ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [i686-linux]
What are your test scores?
12,34 66
37
arup@linux-wzza:~/Ruby>
```

Comment: @nmares12 I am able to do this, as you put efforts to make your question much clear to us about your pain and requirement.